# Android: How to expand rectangular image with same ratio to fit the screen

Tags: android, imageview

I have the following rectangular image to be set in my application.

[image]

Now I am trying to expand the image with same ratio on both sides until it fits to the screen.But I cant get the expected image.

[image]

So far my code is :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/shayneward"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

It dont care that the image gets cut off, but it should expand on both sides with same ratio until it fits to the screen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` to get the behavior that you want.

The different scaling options are documented under [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

Answer (score 5):

Try using this:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

From the Android documentation, center crop does the following:

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that
>   both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or
>   larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

See documentation for `ImageView.ScaleType` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

Comment: You've got the correct scaling type here, but the wrong constant -- in XML it should be "centerCrop", not "CENTER_CROP".

Comment: Thank you, I accidentally put the constant you use if setting it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

if the image is too small could be a problem because it is not scaled to fit screen dimensions.

I use this class to solve this issue:

```
public class FixedCenterCrop extends ImageView {


    public FixedCenterCrop(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    public FixedCenterCrop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    public FixedCenterCrop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        recomputeImgMatrix();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        recomputeImgMatrix();
        return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);
    }

    private void recomputeImgMatrix() {
        final Matrix matrix = getImageMatrix();

        float scale;
        final int viewWidth = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
        final int viewHeight = getHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
        final int drawableWidth = getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        final int drawableHeight = getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

        if (drawableWidth * viewHeight > drawableHeight * viewWidth) {
            scale = (float) viewHeight / (float) drawableHeight;
        } else {
            scale = (float) viewWidth / (float) drawableWidth;
        }

        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        matrix.postTranslate((viewWidth - drawableWidth * scale) / 2, (viewHeight - drawableHeight*scale)/2);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
}
```